# The issue with "pod install" while trying to integrate Firebase and RN GoogleSignin

Tags: windows, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, google-signin

Edit: I am using the command on Windows.
The issue when I run the following command `pod install`.

The error that it generates:

```
    Installing unimodules:
    Analyzing dependencies
    Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
    Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
    Fetching podspec for `RNGestureHandler` from `../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/RNGestureHandler.podspec`
    Fetching podspec for `RNReanimated` from `../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec`
    Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
    Downloading dependencies
    Installing AppAuth (1.3.0)
    Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
    Installing EXAppLoaderProvider (8.0.0)
    Installing EXConstants (8.0.0)
    Installing EXErrorRecovery (1.0.0)
    Installing EXFileSystem (8.0.0)
    Installing EXFont (8.0.0)
    Installing EXKeepAwake (8.0.0)
    Installing EXLinearGradient (8.0.0)
    Installing EXLocation (8.0.0)
    Installing EXPermissions (8.0.0)
    Installing EXSQLite (8.0.0)
    Installing EXWebBrowser (8.0.0)
    Installing FBLazyVector (0.61.5)
    Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.61.5)
    Installing Folly (2018.10.22.00)
    Installing GTMAppAuth (1.0.0)
    Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.3.0)
    Installing GoogleSignIn (5.0.2)

    [!] Error installing GoogleSignIn
    [!] C:/WINDOWS/system32/tar.exe xfz C:/Users/PREETS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/d20191228-9184-epkk3u/file.tgz -C C:/Users/PREETS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/d20191228-9184-epkk3u --force-local

    tar.exe: Option --force-local is not supported
    Usage:
      List:    tar.exe -tf <archive-filename>
      Extract: tar.exe -xf <archive-filename>
      Create:  tar.exe -cf <archive-filename> [filenames...]
      Help:    tar.exe --help
```

I have been struggling with these errors for days. Please help.

Comment: Maybe related to https://www.howtogeek.com/442609/confirmed-windows-10-setup-now-prevents-local-account-creation/?

Comment: Actually, I've been looking for a solution. The second problem is maybe related to the tar.exe file that comes inbuilt in Windows. But I'm unable to delete it. And I'm not sure where to specify a path for the git tar.exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the question was incomplete. Now that I have completed it and I know its answer, I will answer it myself.

It is not possible to create an iOS app on Windows OS. At least, not directly through the command line.